# android listview refresh issue data come from server

Tags: android, listview, server

I have two problem one is listview which have data which come from server. Now problem is that, this listview does not refresh data how can I slove my problem.I use intent to refresh my data data refresh correct but on same page i have text view which come from other activity when i use intent textview data gone please tell me how can i solve it.
here is the listview which show data.

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
                new String[]{TAG_DATA},
                new int[]{R.id.data}

        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is text view whose text come from other activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        Remail = extras.getString("email");
        e1.setText(extras.getString("email"));
```

thanks

```
 protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                //String sender_email = c.getString(TAG_SENDER_EMAIL);
               // String reciver_email = c.getString(TAG_RECIVER_EMAIL);
                String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
                //       String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
               // e2.setText(sender_email);

                HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                //           persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
                user_data.put(TAG_DATA, data);
                //      users.put(TAG_EMAIL,email);

                personList.add(user_data);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
                    new String[]{TAG_DATA},
                    new int[]{R.id.data}

            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

data get from server

```
public void getData() {
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //String recID = ;
        //String userID = email;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://samplechatapp.gear.host/myphpfile.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.i("",result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborate? Paste the code where you are putting the new data into the listView

Comment: try this to refresh your `listView`  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

Comment: @Aradhna check now

Comment: @MasoomBacha but what happens when you refresh this? Where is the code when you get new data and then you add it to your personList and use notifySetDataChanged() on your adapter?

Comment: when i refresh with intent my textview data gone but listdata updated correct

Comment: i updated code please check it

Comment: Where do people learn that is how to use an AsyncTask? 1) classes shouldn't be in methods 2) don't share a global variable within it, use a callback appropriately. That being said, using Volley would aid in both those steps